# Minimization over two lines

Tags: calculus, functions, convex-optimization

This is a minimization question where the minimizing points can be chosen freely on two lines:
$$\mbox{minimize}\, \prod_{i=1}^K {y_i}\quad \mbox{such that}\quad \prod_{i=1}^K {y_i}=1-\prod_{i=1}^K(1-x_i)$$

where every $(x_i,y_i)$ is either a point on the line $l_1:y=\theta(1-x)$ or a point on the line $l_2:y=\theta^{-1}(\theta-x)$. Note that $l_2$ is the inverse function of $l_1$.

The lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ are restricted to the window $[0,1]^2$. $\theta,x_i$, and $y_i$ can take values only in $(0,1)$

If we can select all $(x_i,y_i)$ only on $l_1$ then $y_i=\theta(1-x_i)$. Writing this in the condition of minimization above

$$\prod_{i=1}^K {y_i}=1-\prod_{i=1}^Ky_i/\theta$$ Then simply it gives $$\prod_{i=1}^K {y_i}={\theta^K\over 1+\theta^K}$$

I wonder if we are free to choose every $(x_i,y_i)$ not only on $l_1$ but also on $l_2$, can we get a lower $$\prod_{i=1}^K {y_i}$$ in terms of $\theta$ and $K$.

---

**From  Yulia V's answer:**

It seems that the problem further reduces to

$$\mbox{minimize}\, \frac{\prod_{i=1}^M ((1-\theta)/y_i + \theta)}{\theta^{K-M}}\quad \mbox{such that}\quad \theta^{K-M}\prod_{i=1}^M {y_i}+\prod_{i=1}^M (1- \theta+\theta y_i)>1$$

Comment: Your wording is slightly unclear to me. Is $\theta,x_i, y_i \in[0,1]$ the additional constraint or are you making the observation that the results should belong to this interval given the other constraints that we have?

Comment: @YuliaV The lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ are defined on the square $[0,1]^2$. For example if $\theta=1/4$ is chosen (which can be chosen only in $(0,1)$), then for $l_1:y=(1/4)*(1-x)$ and $x$ can take $(0,1)$ so $y\in[0,1/4]$. For $l_2$, if $x=0$, then $y=1$. $x$ can be at most $\theta$ and for this choice $y=0$ because lines are restricted to $[0,1]^2$. Accordingly for $l_2$, $y\in[0,1]$ but $x\in[0,1/4]$   Coming to your question, I think it is the restriction from where $(x_i,y_i)$ can come on the lines.

Comment: I have posted the beginning of the answer to your question. It will be quite long I think, I am not sure I would be able to finish it, but if you could set a bounty, it would help :)

Comment: @YuliaV I can put a bounty but I am not sure if I will get an answer eventually..

Comment: if I solve it, could you promise to put a bounty and give it to me?

Comment: @YuliaV YES, definitely, no worries about it. Or I can put a bounty now but in this case I would request you to delete the answer until it is complete. Both are fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

*This is the beginning of your problem study. I believe you can finish it using this approach, but there are many cases to study... Please check my algebra.*

Let the answer include $M$ points such that $1-y_i=\frac{x_i}{\theta}$, $K-M$ points such that to $1-x_i=\frac{y_i}{\theta}$.

We will compute the answer for each $M\in\{0,1,\dots,K\}$, then pick $M$ that yields overall minimum product of $y$.

**$M<K$ case**

Let us do the optimization in $2$ steps. Firstly, for a given set of $y_1,\dots,y_M$ let us find the optimal $y_{M+1},\dots,y_K$. Then, let us optimise the result over $y_1,\dots,y_M$.

The first step consists of minimizing $\prod_{k=1}^K y_k$ given $y_1,\dots,y_M$, $x_1,\dots,x_M$,  and $$\prod_{k=1}^K y_k = 1 - \prod_{k=1}^M (1-x_k) 
\frac{\prod_{k=M+1}^K y_k}{\theta^{K-M} }$$
on $y_{M+1}\in[0,\theta], \dots, y_{K}\in[0,\theta]$. This is equivalent to the following constaint

$$\prod_{k=M+1}^K y_k = \frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^M y_k +  
\frac{\prod_{k=1}^M (1-\theta + \theta y_k)}{\theta^{K-M} }} < \theta^{M}$$

Thus, we need to minimize 
$\prod_{k=1}^K y_k = \frac{1}{1 +  
\frac{\prod_{k=1}^M (1-\theta + \theta y_k)/y_k}{\theta^{K-M} }}$, or maximize $$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^M (1-\theta)/y_k + \theta }{\theta^{K-M} }$$ conditional on $$\prod_{k=1}^M y_k +  
\frac{\prod_{k=1}^M (1-\theta + \theta y_k)}{\theta^{K-M} } > \theta^{-M}$$

Maximum value can be achieved if $y_i=0$, and this is only possible if $ (1-\theta)^{M}  > \theta^{K-2M}$; the minimum of $\prod_{k=1}^K y_k$ will be $0$.

Comment: I guess $<\theta^M$ should be $<\theta^{K-M}$. In this case $y_i=0$ can not be a solution, because it wont satisfy the constraint. If $y_i=0$ then the constaint holds iff $x_i=1$, then $(x_i,y_i)$ is neither on $l_1$ nor on $l_2$

Comment: please see the edit.